# Could I use a HTML button to save a string as a text file?

Tags: html, button, text, download, save

I am a newbie on HTML.

Could I use a HTML button to save a string as a text file? I got the following code in Internet. It works very well, with a link (It doesn't work with Internet Explorer.) I would like to have this feature with a button.

```js
var fileName = 'myfile.txt';
var fileContent = 'Page content...';
var myFile = new Blob([fileContent], {
  type: 'text/plain'
});
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(myFile));
document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('download', fileName);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Text File Download Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="" id="download">Download</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need a button, or something that looks like a button? Why don't you just format your **anchor tag** so it looks like a button? I know this doesn't answer your question, but may give a practical hint to solve a problem.

Comment: A anchor tag worked. 

Thanks a lot!!!!